# Is there a way to display an email using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am looking for a view to display an email on the IPhone. Is there something similar to MFMailComposeViewController?. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There's exactly MFMailComposeViewController. Not sure what you're asking?

Comment: MFMailComposeViewController can be used to compose email, what if I want to display an email; i.e. I have all the fields to display an email (to, from, cc, subject, time, body etc.), I want to display it exactly how the apple mail client does. Is there a way around?

Comment: You mean display only? Not making an email that can be sent?

Answer (score 0):

I used [TTMessageController](http://three20.info/api/TTMessageController) and modified it to create this control